# How to restore a recovery point on a windows 7 that won't boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, bsod, system-recovery

I was trying to analyze what was causing slow boot on my Windows 7 machine and installed Windows Performance Analysis Tools (following [those](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/146919-install-the-windows-performance-tool-kit-wpt/) instructions). After that I set it up for boot tracing (based on [those](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140247-trace-windows-7-bootshutdownhibernatestandbyresume-issues/) instructions). Unfortunately I'm one of those people who get a BSOD during a boot because of including drivers in the boot trace. The instruction warned about it and even gave a solution how to solve. I need to restore a recovery point from before the boot trace was set (or from before the tools were installed).

I googled a bit on my alternative computer, but I was unable to find information how to restore a recovery point if I cannot even boot Windows (I thought about using safe mode, but for some reason I cannot get the menu for starting it either). I admit the information is probably out there. All I could find was myriads of pages offering exact same instruction for restoring a recovery point from running windows 7, hence this question.

The computer with the problem is running Windows 7 64 bit version. As far as available tools go, I can't find my install disk for Windows 7 64 bit (though I found one for the 32 bit version). I'm mentioning that because my gut is telling me I might be able to perform the recovery if I had the install disk, but can I? I probably have the image stored somewhere so I should still be able to burn it. I have a Windows Live CD (made out of Windows XP) and it should have img burn among other tools.

---

Update:
For reasons unknown Windows XP live BSODs (I suspect it's incompatible with my hardware). I tested a Windows 7 disc that I found and from what I see it appears to possible to restore a recovery point using it, however this is a 32 bit Windows 7 disc and I need a 64 bit one to fix a 64 bit system. That's why now I'm downloading a copy of Windows 7 from the legit sources mentioned by and31415. I mean I probably have the image on the computer already, but since I can't even boot Windows XP Live, alternative methods of burning the thing are going to be slightly more annoying (I need a new Linux stick and a Windows 7 Live).

Comment: If you need a Windows 7 64-bit setup media, see here: [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)

Comment: @and31415 Thanks a lot. This actually helped me as I was unable to do a recovery using my Windows 7 32 bit disc. I burned the Win7 64 bit image, did the recovery and windows is back alive. I'd post what exactly I did as an answer, but it seems I'm too much of a noob here to be able to answer my own question right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 installation disc did the trick. I restored a previous recovery point and my system boots up again.

There are various tools on the disc and recovery was one of those. It should be noted that the version of the system has to match, I mean one can't recover 64bit version using 32bit disc and vice versa.

The tools are available after booting from the disc, selecting installation language and choosing the tools (smaller menu item) instead of a regular installation (big menu item).

I would have done this from the start if I had my Windows 7 64bit disc around (I believe I installed from the image without burning it on a disc somehow). and31415 helped a lot by [pointing to a location](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) where I can download a copy of my system.